# Covariance in PoseWithCovariance

Tags: geometry-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How is the covariance field in the PoseWithCovariance
message interpreted?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12344/covariance-in-posewithcovariance/) by [Hordur](https://answers.ros.org/users/418/hordur/) on ROS Answers with karma: 544 on 2011-12-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The "msg.covariance" field represents the uncertainty in the deterministic field "msg.pose".

This uncertainty is described by a [normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) centered on the pose field so the probability of the state x follows:  p(x)~ N(msg.pose,msg.covariance)

---

Originally posted by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) with karma: 2982 on 2012-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) on 2012-02-15**:
Of course there is others ways to represent the pose uncertainty. For instance the PoseArray msg (particles) makes possible describing a more complex probabilistic distribution. In any case it has some drawbacks, most of algorithms based on particles usually have less computational efficence.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Off the top of my head, I can only think of one [node](http://www.ros.org/wiki/robot_pose_ekf) that might use it. It's interpreted by different nodes in different fashions. The covariance represents the trustworthiness of a measurement. Many programs don't care about this value, and each one that does handles it differently.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-12-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1